# Is it possible to set "x:Class" more than one into a ResourceDictionary file?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, ivalueconverter

I have a `ResourceDictionary` file and also I have two classes to use for it.
 One of them is `IValueConverter` and the other is for the `EventHandlers` related to the control.
 The class name is `EventHandlers` set as `x:Class` attribute value.
 I also need to set `Converters` as a second `x:Class`.
 But I can't do it because the designer throws an error that says `x:Class is set more than one time`.
 How can I solve this issue?

**Converters.cs**

```
 class Converters : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double pr = (double)value;
        AltoProgressBar bar = parameter as AltoProgressBar;
        return pr * bar.Width / bar.Maximum;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EventHandlers.cs**

```
public partial class EventHandlers 
{
    private void progressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        ProgressBar progressBar = sender as ProgressBar;
        var template = progressBar.Template;

        //Find the Rectangle in the ControlTemplate
        var layer = (Rectangle)(template.FindName("rect", progressBar));

        //Calculate the increment amount depending maxValue and Width
        double artis = progressBar.Value * progressBar.Width / progressBar.Maximum;

        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(toValue: artis, duration: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

        layer.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.WidthProperty, anim);
    }
}
```

**styles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AltoSS"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="AltoSS.Converters" 
                <!--this doesn't make any sense-->
                x:Class="AltoSS.EventHandlers">
<!--All styles in here-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Setting x:Class on a ResourceDictionary doesn't make sense. It would mean that the ResourceDictionary is derived from that class. What you certainly want is a XML namespace declaration like `xmlns:altoss="clr-namespace:AltoSS"` and then instantiate things like converters in the dictionary like `<altoss:Converters .../>` (bad class name btw). Again, you should start reading documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats not possible to set the x:Class-Attribute multiple times (polymorphism aims).

If you only want to use your class Converters (more specific name would be nicer) and your EventHandeler you need to define the namespaces of both classes in RD-Tag (similar to xmlns:YourNamespace=clr-namespace:YourProject.NamespaceName).

Then you can define your Converters with x:Key as Static Resource.

like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AltoSS"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:AltoConverters="AltoSS.NamespaceConverters" 
            xmlns:AltoEventHandlers="AltoSS.NamespaceEventHandlers">
            <!--NamespaceConverters and NamespaceEventHandlers from your cs files -->

 <!-- for use as static Resource -->    
 <AltoConverters:Converters x:Key="YourConverters" />

     <!-- example -->
     <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ...Path..., Converter={StaticResource YourConverters}" />
     </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```